# Time complexity analysis of backtracking classic n-queens

Tags: algorithm, big-o, backtracking, n-queens

I have been reading some code of solving the classic n-queens problem. It is just to find one solution(not all of them or to count the # of solutions). You can find complete code on [geeksforgeeks website](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-set-3-n-queen-problem/), which is summed up below. **The question is, what's the time complexity of this code, really**?

```
bool isSafe(int board[N][N], int row, int col)
{
    int i, j;

    /* Check this row on left side */
    for (i = 0; i < col; i++)
        if (board[row][i])
            return false;

    /* Check upper diagonal on left side */
    for (i=row, j=col; i>=0 && j>=0; i--, j--)
        if (board[i][j])
            return false;

    /* Check lower diagonal on left side */
    for (i=row, j=col; j>=0 && i<N; i++, j--)
        if (board[i][j])
            return false;

    return true;
}

/* A recursive utility function to solve N
   Queen problem */
bool solveNQUtil(int board[N][N], int col)
{
    /* base case: If all queens are placed
      then return true */
    if (col >= N)
        return true;

    /* Consider this column and try placing
       this queen in all rows one by one */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        /* Check if queen can be placed on
          board[i][col] */
        if ( isSafe(board, i, col) )
        {
            /* Place this queen in board[i][col] */
            board[i][col] = 1;

            /* recur to place rest of the queens */
            if ( solveNQUtil(board, col + 1) )
                return true;

            /* If placing queen in board[i][col]
               doesn't lead to a solution, then
               remove queen from board[i][col] */
            board[i][col] = 0; // BACKTRACK
        }
    }

     /* If queen can not be place in any row in
        this colum col  then return false */
    return false;
}

/* This function solves the N Queen problem using
   Backtracking. It mainly uses solveNQUtil() to
   solve the problem. It returns false if queens
   cannot be placed, otherwise return true and
   prints placement of queens in the form of 1s.
   Please note that there may be more than one
   solutions, this function prints one  of the
   feasible solutions.*/
bool solveNQ()
{
    int board[N][N] = { {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    if ( solveNQUtil(board, 0) == false )
    {
      printf("Solution does not exist");
      return false;
    }

    printSolution(board);
    return true;
}
```

If you went through the history of comments, some said it's `O(n!)`, or even exponential. But I think neither of them is correct.

E.g., for claim of `O(n!)`, one gave `T(n)= n*(T(n-1) + O(n))` which leads to `O(n!)`.

### **Why I think it's wrong(not `O(n!)`)?**

1.The problem is, the `for` loop in `solveNQUtil` always runs `N` times. It doesn't decrease with problem scope `n`. So the multiplier `n` in the above formula is not correct. It should be replaced with a fixed number `N`.

2.`col` in `isSafe` increases down the recursion tree, which means the `for` loop in `isSafe` has more and more iterations. The # of iterations is `N - n`.

So basically, the recursion should be `T(n)= N *(T(n-1) + O(N - n))` (N is fixed). Not sure how to solve this one, but it's should be at least `O(N^N)`. **Any idea?**

### Recursion tree method

If using a recursion tree, there are `O(n^n)` different paths down to the leaves, and each path takes `O(1+2+..n)` operations for conflict check. So total time should be `O(n^(n+2))`. **Is this right?**

Could anyone point out if this is correct and give appropriate reasonings?

Answer (score 2):

It is a very good observation. Put me in lot of thinking and simulation of the steps.

By looking only at code and trying to derive the complexity, you are actually right that it should be O(n^n).

But the catch is that though the inner loop in `solveNQUtil` running N times, the recursive function `solveNQUtil` is not being called N times. In worst case it will be called `n-1` times. Because each of the previous columns has one queen is them so as the columns are iterated, one of the row is being dropped from further consideration. So instead of recurrence be

```
T(n)= N *(T(n-1))
```

it is indirectly indeed

```
T(n)= n *(T(n-1))
```

Comment: Thanks. That's true. When one more recursive call is made, at least one more `isSafe` should return false. So the # of `for` iterations decreases by at least 1 per recusive call. And for the overhead in `isSafe`, since `col` rows has been filled already, there are at most `min(col, N-col+1)` iterations of `for (i = 0; i < col; i++)`. So the recurrence is truely `T(n)= n*(T(n-1) + O(n))`.

Comment: Hey, I gave it a second thought. The recurrence should be `T(n) = n*T(n-1) + N*n` which leads to `O((n+1)!)` instead of `O(n!)`. This is because although the number of recursion calls decreases, the number of `for` loop iterations in `solveNQUtil()` remains the same(`N`). What do you think?

Comment: Just tell me how that recurrence ended up in O(n+1 !). Try out taking some simple example and let me know what you find out. It is turning out as good complexity analysis exercise :). Though you are right that N*n term will also add up.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:- Keep in mind that we are calculating worst case time complexity

your function solveNQUtil() uses a for loop have a range of 'n' and it will call itself for (n-1) times more to fill all the rows.
moreover, we are using a function isSafe() to check if queen is safe at that particular position.

we get a Recurrence relation [ T(n) = n*T(n-1) + O(N-n) ]
where T(0) = O(1)

O(N-n) < O(N)

so, recurrence relation will be [ T(n) = n*T(n-1) + O(N) ]

T(n-1) = (n-1)*T(n-2) + O(N)

T(n-2) = (n-2)*T(n-3) + O(N)

T(n-3) = (n-3)*T(n-4) + O(N)

..

..

..

..

..

..

..

T(n-k+1) = (n-k+1)*T(n-k) + O(N)

So, T(n) = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)*.....*(n-k+1)*T(n-1) + k*O(N)

if k=n

T(n) = n!*T(0) + n*O(N)

T(n) = n! + O(N^2)

hence , T(n) = O(n!)

Hope it helped you or may be others